# Using real analysis, how can we show that for all $x > 0$, $ \frac{2(e^x-(1+x))}{x^2} < e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was able to think that the numerator will always be positive and will overpower the denominator as well. But couldn't proceed from there.

Comment: This is only true for $x>0$.

Comment: I forgot to add that. Will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Consider the power series expansion of $e^x=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.  Then 
$$e^x-\frac{2(e^x-(1+x))}{x^2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}-2\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac{x^{k-2}}{k!}=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!}-2\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^{k}}{(k+2)!}\\=\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^k}{k!}\left(1-\frac{2}{(k+2)(k+1)}\right).$$
Show that the coefficients of the resulting power series are all positive.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Mean-value forms of the remainder of [Taylor's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) you get the existence of $c \in (0,x)$ such that
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}e^c$$ Hence 
$$e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}e^c <1+x+\frac{x^2}{2} e^x$$ and the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $f(x)=x^2e^x-2(e^x-(1+x)),x>0.$ Then
$$f^{'}(x)=x^2e^x+2xe^x-2(e^x-1)$$ 
and
$$f^{''}(x)=x^2e^x+2xe^x+2xe^x+2e^x-2e^x=x^2e^x+4xe^x>0.$$